# dataview in using statement

Tags: asp.net

I am using DataView with using statement as in the following:

```
DataTable dt = /*Fetch data from database*/
using (DataView dv = dt.DefaultView)
{
  dv.RowFilter = “Filter string”;
}
```

It works fine on page load. (`IsPostback = false`).

When my page posts back and the same piece of code is executed, `dv` returns null. (may be becasue `dv` was diposed on page load?)

If I remove the using statement than everything works fine even on post back.

My understating is that we should use using statement with every object that inherits “IDisposible”.

Can somebody explain why wrapping the `dv` in a `using` statement doesnt' work?

Comment: could you show us your `ispostback` condition here. ?

Comment: Disposing an object doesn't make it null. You must have another problem. This situation can happen if you have another variable named dv in an outer scope.

Comment: Actually, I checked and dv doesn't return null. It has data with column names but rows are cleared. I haven't used dv in other place.

Comment: It seems that If object is disposed on page load than it will be cleared and can not be assigned value, even if we assign it manually. Is is a good practice to use using statement with dataview?